# Preventing a method being called before another one

Tags: java, c++, methods, call

This is question is a bit broad and conceptual.

I have a class with various methods. Let's call them `A` and `B`. How can I make sure that other developers working with this class in the future will not call method B before first calling method A at least once ?

I am doing this in C++ but in general what's the best way to enforce this ? I have naive some ideas such as using a boolean variable but I would like to hear some other thoughts as well.

Comment: you cannot really enforce the order (you already have a solution mentioned). You may able to re-design with template pattern and avoid this special need.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One way to guarantee this?  Make it the responsibility of method B to call method A once.

Anything else is a fragile API.

Comment: This is a good idea(+1), Note that a disadvantage to this is that all the information needed to make the call to A must be passed into B - this can be sad. (Imagine needing to pass all your DB connection data to every query... )

Comment: Also "Only way" is a bit strong IMO.

Answer (score 7):

One way is to redesign your class a little differently.  Consider a simple database class that needs to be initialized before being used.  I'm a Java guy, so...

```
public class Database {
  public void init(String username, String password) // must call this first!
  public List<Object> runQuery(String sql) // ...
}
```

So I need to call init first.  I can make a DatabaseFactory that does the initialization and returns the actual database object.  We can hide the constructor so that only a DatabaseFactory can create a Database (in Java a nested class, in C++ a friend class maybe?).

```
public class DatabaseFactory {
   public Database init(String username, String password) // ...

   public class Database {
     private Database() {}
     public List<Object> runQuery(String sql) // ...
   }
}
```

So now I must go through the Factory to get to the underlying object.

```
DatabaseFactory factory = new DatabaseFactory();
Database database = factory.init("username", "password"); // first init (call method A)
// now I can use database (or B in your case)
database.runQuery("select * from table");
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a boolean variable that determines if `A` has been called. Then, when someone tries to invoke `B` without this boolean variable being set, throw an IllegalStateException.

Or you could have `B` simply call `A` since it seems that it cannot execute without `A` being called first anyways.

Otherwise, and since both methods are public, there's really no other way to enforce this.

Answer (score 5):

Using a boolean is a good start, and throwing on access works OK.

However sometimes its nice to be able to enforce this at compile-time. In that case your only real option is to use some tricks.

Only expose A in your class, make it return a proxy containing B.

```
class MyClass {
  public:

    struct BProxy {
      public:
        MyClass * root;
        void B() { root->B(); }
      protected:
        BProxy( MyClass * self ) : root(self) {}; // Disable construction
        friend class MyClass; //So that MyClass can construct it
    };

    BProxy A() { ... return BProxy(this); }
    friend class BProxy; // So that BProxy can call B()
  protected
   void B() { ... }
};

int main() {
   MyClass m;
   BProxy bp = m.A(); 
   // m.B(); can't do this as it's private - will fail at compile time.
   bp.B(); // Can do this as we've got the proxy from our previous call to A.
}
```

You can also achieve something similar using protected inheritance from a baseclass implementing (or providing a virtual) B().

Answer (score 2):

One way to guarantee it is that `A` is done in the constructor of the class. If the constructor fails (throws) then the other developers do not have anything with what to do that erroneous `B` with. If the constructor succeeds then `A` is done at least once and so `B` is valid operation to do.

Answer (score 2):

I would make method "A" the constructor to initialise the object.  This has to called once to use the object, enforced by the compiler. Later you can call a method "B" in the knowledge that a constructor must have been called.